# Spring MVC error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I'm pretty much completely new to the world of computer programming, so it's been something of a struggle getting a really in depth understanding of many concepts. Right now, I'm working on a project in which we are implementing Spring MVC. The first step in the project is to make a login page for a website. I've tried modelling mine after one that we did in class, but I can't seem to get past the following error in my web browser:

```
Unsupported auto value type java.lang.String for field injuryReports.Login.userName
```

Here is my Login entity class:

```
package injuryReports;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Login implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private int userId;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Login() {
    }

    public Login(String userName, String password) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Login(int userId, String userName2, String password2) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName2;
        this.password = password2;
    }
}
```

My LoginDao Class:

```
package injuryReports;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * 
 * @author nGent
 *
 */

@Component
public class LoginDao {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void persist(Login user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }

    public List<Login> getAllUsers() {
        TypedQuery<Login> query = em.createQuery(
                "Select u FROM Login u ORDER BY u.id", Login.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Login validateLogin(String userName, String password) {
        Login login = null;
        TypedQuery<Login> query = em.createQuery(
                "Select u From Login u where u.userName = :userName " +
                " and u.password = :password", Login.class).setParameter(
                "userName", userName).setParameter("password", password);
        try {
            login = query.getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: Handle Exception
        }
        return login;
    }
}
```

And my LoginController class:

```
package injuryReports;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView userEntry(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (userName != "" && password != "") {
            loginDao.persist(new Login(userName, password));
        }

        return new ModelAndView("logon.jsp", "loginDao", loginDao);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String page = "login.jsp";

        if (userName != "" && password != "") {
            try {
                Login login = loginDao.validateLogin(userName, password);
                if (login != null) {
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("UserId", login.getUserId());
                    page = "login.jsp";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO: Handle Exception
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView(page, getDaos());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logon", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView logon(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //int userId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("userId");
        //request.getSession().setAttribute("UserID", userId);
        return new ModelAndView("logon.jsp", getDaos());
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getDaos() {
        Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        models.put("loginDao", loginDao);
        return models;
    }
}
```

Sorry this is a bit long- I wanted to provide as much information as possible. I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: You're annotating the wrong ID field; use the... well, the `userId` field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use [`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) on `String` property. It uses database sequences or `AUTOINCREMENT` features depending on the underlying database engine.

Either remove this annotation:

```
@Id
private String userName;
```

or use integer/long for id:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int userId;
```